# Why is non-degeneracy of forms an open condition?

Tags: differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

I've recently begun a self-study of symplectic geometry (and forms in general), and just read through the proof of the Darboux theorem. Thus far, all of the sources I've found universally use a 'fact' that's not immediately clear to me. Here I state it more formally:

> Let $M$ be a (finite-dimensional) smooth manifold and $X \subset M$ a compact submanifold. If a $2$-form $\omega$ is non-degenerate on $X$, then it is also non-degenerate on some open neighborhood $U$ of $X$.

I interpret this as saying that non-degeneracy is an open condition. To prove this, it suffices to show that if $\omega$ is non-degenerate at a point $p \in M$ (that is, $\omega_p : T_p M \times T_p M \to \mathbb{R}$ is non-degenerate), then it is non-degenerate in a neighborhood of $p$. We could then construct such neighborhoods around all the boundary points of $X$ and glue them together get a choice in $U$.

Since this is a local problem, we can consider a chart $V$ centered at $p$, with the induced local basis of vector fields denoted by $\{\partial_i\}$. Since $\omega_p$ is non-degenerate, the map $\omega(\partial_1\vert_p, \ \cdot): T_p M \to \mathbb{R}$ is not identically zero. Hence it cannot vanish on all basis vectors and (up to reordering) we may assume that $\omega(\partial_1\vert_p, \partial_2\vert_p) \neq 0$. Since the coordinate vector fields depend smoothly on the base point $p$ and $\omega$ is smooth,  $\omega(\partial_1\vert_q, \partial_2\vert_q) \neq 0$ for all $q$ in some neighborhood $V$ of $p$. Hence $\omega$ is non-degenerate on $V$.

Does this argument suffice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a real-valued continuous function does not vanish at a point, it does not vanish in a neighborhood of that point. $\omega_p$ is non degenerate means that its rank is maximal i.e. the associated musical morphism
$$\begin{array}{cccc}
\sharp : &T_pM&\to&T_p^*M\\
&x&\mapsto&\sharp(x)(y):=\omega_p(x,y)
\end{array}$$
has a non-zero determinant, therefore do not vanish in a neighborhood of $p$.

---

Using the same argument, we can show that the following properties are open: being a submersion, immersion, transversal (here we speak of stability).